# MySQL's LIKE operator doesn't find phone number that matches exactly

Tags: mysql, sql-like

this is my first question here, having a strange problem with MySQL:
I have phone numbers in a database field 'phone' of type varchar(50)    utf8mb4_unicode_ci. Type is varchar, because the numbers can have delimiters like / or - and spaces for formatting.

If I select the phone number with:

```
SELECT phone, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone,' ',''),'-',''),'/',''),'.','') FROM [table] WHERE id=405760
```

the output is:
0151 / ‎434 77 588, 0151‎43477588

So the REPLACE part does work, also, when I select the

But searching after those phone numbers with the LIKE operator fails for this specific phone number 015143477588 (others work perfectly):

```
SELECT *
FROM [table]
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone,' ',''),'-',''),'/',''),'.','') like '%015143477588%'
```

If I use the = instead LIKE it works.

```
SELECT *
FROM [table]
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone,' ',''),'-',''),'/',''),'.','') = '015143477588'
```

as said, other phone numbers work....any ideas?

Comment: Is really space, / and - parts of the number or are they parts of the display of the numbers? I would have stored only the number, probably storing country code in a separate column so + also can be filtered out, and only have spacing etc. as part of the UI. If you need to store it with all formatting options, use a different column to store the the clean number and always query against the clear number

Comment: Good job on your first question. Welcome to Stack Overflow. But what's with the `[table]` syntax? That's SQL Server talk.

Comment: Seeing 4 nested REPLACE functions i really doubt your data in the phone column.. You should really fix your format and create a trigger to enforce the phone format.

Comment: trim phone number before replace may its work, as i tested as per your requirement its working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your query in my database it is working fine

`SELECT * 
 FROM users
 WHERE REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( phone,  ' ',  '' ) ,  '-',  '' ) 
 ,  '/',  '' ) ,  '.',  '' ) 
LIKE  '%015143477588%'`

You can check your query after change `Collation` from `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to `utf8_swedish_ci`